# Disable Select Box Directive when Check Box is Checked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 2 select directive in my html  and want to diasble them when the     checkbox is checked... how can i do ?? I have added `ng-model="ckecked"` to `input type="ckeckbox"` and `ng-disabled` to directives but they aren't working.

```
**year Drop Directive.js**

(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module('components.others').directive('yearDrop',function(){
      function getYears(offset, range){
        var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        var years = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < range + 1; i++){
          var yearStr = ''+ (currentYear + offset - i);
          var newYear = {
            'label': yearStr,
            'value': yearStr
          };
          years.push(newYear);
        }
        return years;
      }
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope:{
            year:'=year'
          },
          link: function(scope,element,attrs){
              scope.years = getYears(+attrs.offset, +attrs.range);
          },
          template: '<select class="form-control" ng-model="year" ng-    options="option.label for option in years track by option.value"><option     value=""> Select Year</option></select>'
      }
    });
})();

HTML

<div class="row" ng-init="checked=true">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="_500">End date</label>
                <year-drop year="employment.endDateYear" offset="0" range="60"></year-drop>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="_500">&nbsp;</label>
                <month-drop month="employment.endDateMonth"></month-drop>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="block _500">&nbsp;</label>
                <label class="block m-t-sm md-check">
                    <input type="checkbox"><i class="blue" ng-model="checked"></i>Current
                </label>
        </div>
    </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You mean ng-model="checked" and input type="checkbox", yes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `ng-model` is in the wrong spot. It should be on the `input` tag, not the `i` tag. Then just use `ng-disabled='checked'`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a custom directive where the template is nested inside, you need to pass through the `ng-disabled` attribute expression to your template:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module('components.others').directive('yearDrop',function(){
      function getYears(offset, range){
        var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        var years = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < range + 1; i++){
          var yearStr = ''+ (currentYear + offset - i);
          var newYear = {
            'label': yearStr,
            'value': yearStr
          };
          years.push(newYear);
        }
        return years;
      }
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope:{
            year:'=year',
            ngDisabled:'='
          },
          link: function(scope,element,attrs){
              scope.years = getYears(+attrs.offset, +attrs.range);
          },
          template: '<select class="form-control" ng-model="year" ng-options="option.label for option in years track by option.value"><option value="" ng-disabled='ngDisabled'> Select Year</option></select>'
      }
    });
})();
```

Then move the `ng-model` attribute to the input (ng-model won't work on non-inputs) so that you can use it on your select directive.

```
<year-drop year="employment.endDateYear" offset="0" range="60" ng-disabled='checked'></year-drop>
```